# ant design collapse component collapses all when device keyboard shows. (on mobile devices)

Tags: antd

I have a textarea inside Collapse component by ant design. When I try to type in something, the Collapse closes and the textarea is unmounted.

Actually, the Collapses closes after every window resize, not just the keyboard.

[page ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgG2G.png)

code

```
      <Collapse
        expandIconPosition="right"
        className="document-settings-collapse"
        activeKey={activeKey}
        onChange={keys => setActiveKey(keys)}
      >
        <Collapse.Panel
          header={<strong>Footer and Watermark settings</strong>}
          key={'1'}
          className="mb-1"
        >
          <FooterAndWatermark
            settings={settings}
            subscription_plan={user.subscription_plan}
            openPaymentPage={openPaymentPage}
          />
        </Collapse.Panel>
      </Collapse>
```

relevant packages

```
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.8",
    "@ant-design/icons": "^4.0.5",
    "antd": "3.26.20",
    "antd-theme-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.1",
```